# Lumia 820 isn't detected in Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I recently bought a Lumia 820. I connected it to windows 7 and worked perfectly, phone was accessible from the file explorer. but when I connect it to windows 8, Lumia 820 is showing in other section in the device manager, not showing in the file explorer. Strange thing is even without seeing the device in my machine I can test the application build through Visual studio by running it on windows phone 8 device. I installed windows phone app to the windows 8, it\s not running, not even giving me an error?

Help me please

Comment: Maybe it's a silly try, but on my Computer, I've got sometimes problem with my Lumia 820, that it's not detected, but when I try different USB port it is recognized. Don't ask why.

Comment: I've had the same problem, seems that the 820 is very sensitive on what USB cable to use! Only the provided stock Nokia cable seems to work, others don't. Wasn't so with my 800!

Comment: I assume you are using Windows 8 N, then check the answer below

Answer (score 1):

if still this problem persists .. try installing windows media feature pack.. it will work like charm..!!

You'll need the most recent Media Pack - search it directly at Microsoft:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=media+feature+pack+for+windows10&form=dlc

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a driver issue.

Try to reinstall your driver using the following steps:

> a.Connect your Windows Phone to your computer by using the USB cable
>   that was included with your phone.
>
> b.Windows 8 users: In the Start
>   screen, type "Device Manager," tap or click Settings, and then tap or
>   click Device Manager. Windows 7, Vista, and XP users: Click Start,
>   right-click Computer, and then click Properties.
>
> c.A window will
>   appear with the name of your computer and a list of files. (If you
>   don't see the files, click the name of your computer.) The name of
>   your Windows Phone 8 should be listed under Portable Devices. If
>   Windows Phone was incorrectly installed, it may be listed with a
>   yellow exclamation mark. Or, it may be listed under Other Devices as a
>   USB device or an unknown device.
>
> d.Double-tap or double-click Windows
>   Phone (under Portable Devices) or the unknown device to open the
>   Properties window.
>
> e.On the Driver tab, tap or click Uninstall.
>
> f.In
>   the pop-up box "Confirm Device Uninstall," select "Delete the driver
>   software for this device" and then tap or click OK.
>
> g.Return to the
>   Device Manager window. Tap or click the Action menu, and then tap or
>   click Scan for hardware changes.
>
> h.Open Portable Devices, double-tap
>   or double-click the name of your Windows Phone, and then click the
>   Driver tab.  Note If you don't see your phone's name, tap or click the
>   unknown device that is listed under Other Devices, and then tap or
>   click the Driver tab.
>
> i.Tap or click Update Driver.
>
> j.Tap or click
>   Browse my computer for driver software.
>
> k.Tap or click Browse, locate
>   the C:\Windows\Inf\ folder on your computer, and then click OK.
>
> l.Click Next and if you're prompted, click Install. You may only be
>   given a Close option.
>
> m.After the driver installation is complete,
>   close the open windows until you exit the Device Manager. Restart your
>   computer if you're prompted.

From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2749484

Comment: This isn't working, windows couldn't find the device driver for the software.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe It is a driver issue. Try installing driver by using these steps

1. open device manager
2. under portable devices look for your device
3. Right click on your device and click update driver software
4. Browse my computer for driver software -> let me pick from a list -> Standard MTP Device
5. After that install MTP Device

This worked for me.